# How do I get the technician with the most repairs and the technician with the least repairs?

Tags: sql

I need to inform 'nombre' and 'especialidad' of the technician with the most repairs and the technician with the least repairs

[this is the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r622L.png)

Comment: Can you please post the table definition as text? This makes it easier for us to help.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Make it easy to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- most repair
select top 1 TechColumn,count(*) as Rcount from TechTable
group by TechColumn
order by Rcount desc

union 

-- least repair
select top 1 TechColumn,count(*) as Rcount from TechTable
group by TechColumn
order by Rcount
```